# Is it possible to integrate Kdb+ and hadoop?

Tags: hadoop, integration, kdb, in-memory-database

Does KDB+ can be integrated with Hadoop like OpensTSDB/MongoDB/Cassandra?

KDB+ works in distributed architecture and supports mapreduce. Is it an alternate option to Hadoop?

Can anyone explain in detail about this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

kdb is a column oriented database plus and array based language q.

I wrote a comparison of the [top column oriented databases](http://www.timestored.com/time-series-data/column-oriented-databases), which should give you an idea of the common competitors.

I consider kdb and hadoop very different, as for the use cases I have seen the overlap is small. What is the problem you are trying to solve?

Sayantan Ghosh wrote this comparison https://www.quora.com/Whats-the-difference-between-Hadoop-and-KDB:

> The major differences are between KDB and Hadoop are :
>
> KDB uses a terse programming language Q. In Q the expressions are
>   evaluated from right to left instead of left to right for other
>   programming languages like Java and C++. Hadoop is based on Java
>   though you can write map reduce jobs in a lot of languages like Java
>   and Python. So, for a programmer, getting the hang of Q may take some
>   time, though it depends from person to person, while I would expect a
>   developer to be up to speed with Hadoop really fast.
>       q-SQL is a SQL like language to query the KDB database. In the hadoop world, the corresponding language is Hive. Hive and q-SQL were
>   mainly built so as to make it easy for business or analyst folks to
>   query the database without prior knowledge of KDB+ or hadoop.
>       KDB+ has an inmemory component called the RDB(real time database) which holds the current days data. The historical data is stored in
>   the historical database(HDB). Hadoop does not have any real time
>   component. It uses the HDFS(Hadoop File System) to store the data.

Comment: Thanks @RyanHamilton for clarifying.

Answer (score 0):

I would post (email) your question to https://groups.google.com/group/personal-kdbplus.  There are many extremely knowledgeable kdb folks there that are eager to help.

Comment: Thanks @Steven Grave for redirecting. That helped.